# Values of variables from command line does not Match in DLL Exported Function

Tags: c++, dll

I have a such difinition of a function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int MyFunc(int param1, const char* param2)
```

whish is only writing parameters into file:

```
WriteLog(std::to_string(param1));
std::string str_param2(param2);
WriteLog(str_param2);
```

I compile and run dll with such command:

```
rundll32 mydll.dll,MyFunc 1 blabla
```

When I print the values I see:

```
4457714
MZђ
```

Why is that so?

How to pass a 1 inside of param1?

Comment: ok, I found a solution

Comment: https://stmxcsr.com/micro/rundll-parse-args.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to declare function as

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

And get parameters like so:

```
int param1 = atoi(lpszCmdLine);
```

Comment: Please note that `std::atoi` have its problems. First of all there's no validation at all. There's no way to differ between the input `"0"` and the input `"foo"`. If you want validation and error handling use `std::stoi` instead. Secondly, you can't use it if you want to pass multiple arguments, then you need to explicitly parse the string.